# Unable to run the web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-405, webapi

I have two `web-apis`

```
 public string GetRData(string data)
    {
        var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

        try
        {
            if(serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
                stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

                //byte[] bytestoread = new byte[9999];
                byte[] bytestosend = StringToByteArray(data);

                serialPort.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
                //receiveData = serialPort.ReadExisting();

                serialPort.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //serial port settings and opening it
                serialPort.Open();
                var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
                stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

                //byte[] bytestoread = new byte[9999];
                byte[] bytestosend = StringToByteArray(data);

                serialPort.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
                //receiveData = serialPort.ReadExisting();

                serialPort.Close();
            }                         

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }


        return data;
    }

    public string GetPData(string id)
    {
        var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
        string receiveData = "";
        try
        {
            //serial port settings and opening it
            serialPort.Open();

            var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
            stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

            //byte[] bytestoread = new byte[9999];
            //byte[] bytestosend = StringToByteArray(data);

            //serialPort.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);
            receiveData = serialPort.ReadExisting();

            serialPort.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


        return receiveData;
    }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "GetRData",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{data}",
       defaults: null

       );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "GetPData",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

      );
```

Whenever I am trying to hit the `GetPData` I am getting below response in `Postman`

> {
>       "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44337/api/rtu/GetPData/1'.",
>       "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'RTU' that matches the request."
>   }

I have searched for this issue but unable to get a solution.

**Note:** The `GetRData` is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are including the action in the URI rather than relying on convention for route matching so you should add attributes to explicitly specify the allowed HTTP verbs:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetPData(string id)
```

Having said that your action does start with "Get" so that should be the verb to which it matches. You should ensure that the request is a "GET". Otherwise the routing looks OK. Have you tried hitting it with the URL:

https://localhost:44337/api/rtu/GetPData?id=1

Comment: by doing `https://localhost:44337/api/rtu/GetPData?id=1` I am getting `value` in return.

Comment: Is that what `serialPort.ReadExisting()` would set `receiveData` to (looking at the code you posted)? If so and you are getting an HTTP 200 response then looks like method is being hit...?

Comment: No it returns a byte array

Comment: A byte array that is decoded to a string using the default encoder (ASCII). When you say it returns `value` do you mean the string `"value" in the response? i.e. the method is called successfully?

Comment: ok I don't know what just happened. I clean up the solution and then build it. Then I run it and called the API now I am getting `Multiple actions were found that match the request: `

Comment: What URL are you using for the request? Do you have any other methods in the controller? Do you have any other routes mapped in WebApiConfig?